# Complexity of Code = n^2?

Tags: java, complexity-theory

What is the complexity of the following code:

```
int data[] = { /* some numbers here */ };
n = data.length;

int lessThanCounter = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=n-1; j>i; j--)
        if (data[i]<data[j]) lessThanCounter++;
```

By my calculations it is O(n^2) - is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your outer loop executes `n` times then the first multiplier is `n`.

The inner loop executes `n-1`, `n-2` ... `0` which is roughly equivalent to `(n-1)/2`.

This therefore executes `n * (n-1)/2` times and is therefore either `O(n^2)` or `O(n^2/2)` depending on which flavour of big-O you are being taught.

NB:  I added the `O(n^2/2)` to pander to the many educational establishments that do not properly understand Big Oh and therefore expect their students to evaluate the Big-Oh of bubble-sort in that way. I apologise for that clearly misleading mistake.

NBB: In case that is not clear `O(n^2/2)` is **wrong** and I knew it was wrong when I posted it. However, if your teacher expects you to put that in your answer just do so. It is unlikely you will ever make progress attempting to explain why it is wrong.

Comment: Which "flavour" of Big-O exists where `O(n^2/2)` is different from `O(n^2)`?

Comment: @sepp2k - <Grin> - The "flavour" of "Big Oh completely misunderstood" - often taught in colleges and many less reputable establishments.

Comment: When you say "n-1, n-2 ... 0 which is equivalent to n/2", you mean that its average is `n/2`, right? That's not quite true though - it's `(n-1)/2`.

Comment: @sepp2k - That is correct mathematically - but in all Big-Oh "flavours" <grin> constants are discarded. It is usually only the multipliers/divisors that are misunderstood. Post adjusted to compensate.

Comment: There is no such thing as O(N^2/2).

Comment: Technically, `O(n^2/2)` is fine. It's exactly the same as the shorter `O(n^2)` or the longer `O(123456789012345*n^2/6)`, so it's "wrong" to use the more verbose forms, but it's not incorrect, @EJP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. The body of the inner loop is executed `n-1` times on the first iteration of the outer loop, `n-2` times on the second iteration and so on until the `n`th iteration when it iterates `n-n = 0` times. So it's executed `n-1 + n-2 + ... + 0 = (n-1)*n/2 = (n^2-n)/2` times total, which is indeed in `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that the running time of your algorithm is O(n^2),
In the first loop

```
for(int i=0:i<n;i++)
```

i goes from 0 to n and the second loop :

```
for(int j = n-1;j>i;j--)
```

j goes from n-1 downto i

The comparisons on `data[i]`, `data[j]` and `lessThanCounter++` are all executed in constant time `O(1)`

Therefore you have this summation:

```
 $\sum_0^{n}(\sum_{n-1}^{i})1$.
```

by eliminating the internal summation you obtain : i+n+2

you now have sum(i=0 to n-1) of (n+i+2)

then sum(i=0 to n-1) of (n+2) + sum(i=0 to n-1) of i   = (n+1)*(n+2) + n(n+1)/2

which is clearly O(n^2)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -3):

You are absolutely right, loop inside loop is O(n^2)

Comment: Not always! It depends on the loop break conditions. But in this case it's true

Comment: That's an oversimplification. It's perfectly possible to have a loop inside a loop with a runtime of O(n log n), O(n sqrt(n)) or even just O(n) (or anything else really).

Comment: Guys, I'm really suggesting you to get back to school, It doesn't matter if you enter the 'if'  statement or not, you iterate the array in O(n^2) complexity!

Comment: @Pavel Nobody suggested that the if mattered (it would only matter if the `if` contained a `break` or a non-`O(1)` operation). We suggested that not every loop inside a loop leads to `O(n^2)` running time.